# Use Pandas groupby() + apply() with arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

I would like to use `df.groupby()` in combination with `apply()` to apply a function to each row per group.

I normally use the following code, which usually works (note, that this is without `groupby()`):

```
df.apply(myFunction, args=(arg1,))
```

With the `groupby()` I tried the following:

```
df.groupby('columnName').apply(myFunction, args=(arg1,))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: myFunction() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Hence, my question is: **How can I use `groupby()` and `apply()` with a function that needs arguments?**

Comment: This would work with `df.groupby('columnName').apply(myFunction, ('arg1'))`

Comment: @Zero this is great answer as it is very similar to OP's attempted solution and doesn't require a lambda. I suggest you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Zero, I have the very same quetsion as the OP, but this doesn't work for me - I still get the very same error as the OP. Also, may I ask why your comment should work and why the OP's approach (which is the same as mine) doesn't? I haven't found it documented anywhere

Comment: try `.apply(myFunction, args = ('arg1',)` note the `,`after `arg1`.

Comment: actually, i just tried it by myself and it doesnt work either...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) does NOT have **named** parameter `args`, but [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) does have it.

So try this:

```
df.groupby('columnName').apply(lambda x: myFunction(x, arg1))
```

or as suggested by [@Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483365/use-pandas-groupby-apply-with-arguments/43483381?noredirect=1#comment79275690_43483365):

```
df.groupby('columnName').apply(myFunction, ('arg1'))
```

Demo:

```
In [82]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
   a  b  c
0  0  3  1
1  0  3  4
2  3  0  4
3  4  2  3
4  3  4  1

In [84]: def f(ser, n):
    ...:     return ser.max() * n
    ...:

In [85]: df.apply(f, args=(10,))
Out[85]:
a    40
b    40
c    40
dtype: int64
```

when using `GroupBy.apply` you can pass either a named arguments:

```
In [86]: df.groupby('a').apply(f, n=10)
Out[86]:
    a   b   c
a
0   0  30  40
3  30  40  40
4  40  20  30
```

a tuple of arguments:

```
In [87]: df.groupby('a').apply(f, (10))
Out[87]:
    a   b   c
a
0   0  30  40
3  30  40  40
4  40  20  30
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no way to pass an `args` parameter here in a tuple?  I've seen that used on `.apply` elsewhere and it obviates the need for a lambda expression.

Comment: @BradSolomon see Zero's answer in the question comments

Comment: Why does this work, while what the OP did doesn't? I'm not following, and I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous, now you have even two answers answering your question :-D

Comment: In my case, I have a function that I need to give two consequent rows to it. How should I do it? df.groupby('columnName').apply(lambda x: myFunction(x, shift(-1))?

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi, try this: `df.groupby('columnName').apply(lambda x: myFunction(x, x.shift(-1))` ;)

Answer (score 9):

Some confusion here over why using an `args` parameter throws an error might stem from the fact that [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) does have an `args` parameter (a tuple), while [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) does not.

So, when you call `.apply` on a DataFrame itself, you can use this argument; when you call `.apply` on a groupby object, you cannot.

In @MaxU's answer, the expression `lambda x: myFunction(x, arg1)` is passed to `func` (the first parameter); there is no need to specify additional `*args`/`**kwargs` because `arg1` is specified in lambda.

An example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Called on DataFrame - `args` is a 1-tuple
# `0` / `1` are just the axis arguments to np.sum
df.apply(np.sum, axis=0)  # equiv to df.sum(0)
df.apply(np.sum, axis=1)  # equiv to df.sum(1)


# Called on groupby object of the DataFrame - will throw TypeError
print(df.groupby('col1').apply(np.sum, args=(0,)))
# TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Answer (score 6):

For me

`df2 = df.groupby('columnName').apply(lambda x: my_function(x, arg1, arg2,))`

worked