# Using Grouped Map Pandas UDFs with arguments

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I want to use `data.groupby.apply()` to apply a function to each row of my Pyspark Dataframe per group.

I used The Grouped Map Pandas UDFs. However I can't figure out how to add  another argument to my function.

I tried using the  argument as a global variable but the function doesn't recognize it (my argument is a pyspark dataframe)
I also tried the solutions proposed in this question (for pandas dataframe) [Use Pandas groupby() + apply() with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483365/use-pandas-groupby-apply-with-arguments?fbclid=IwAR0him137F-4m7rjUVvFzpKO3RRI_K6ZF7FFkPsJvIQdx9RUcVsLk_S0VPM)

```py
      @pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
        def function(key,data, interval):
            interval_df=interval.filter(interval["var"]==key).toPandas()
            for value in interval_df:
                  #Apply some operations

        return Data.groupBy("msn").apply(calc_diff, ('arg1'))
```

Or

```py
 @pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
        def function(key,data, interval):
            interval_df=interval.filter(interval["var"]==key).toPandas()
            for value in interval_df:
                  #Apply some operations

        return Data.groupBy("msn").apply(lambda x: calc_diff(x,'arg1'))
```

But I get the error :

> ValueError: Invalid function: pandas_udfs with function type
> GROUPED_MAP must take either one argument (data) or two arguments
> (key, data).

Could anyone help me with the above issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 22):

I like @hwrd's idea, but instead, would make it a generator pattern to make it easier to integrate like in @Feng's example:

```
def function_generator(key):
    @pandas_udf(schema,PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def function(interval):
        interval_df=interval.filter(interval["var"]==key).toPandas()
        for value in interval_df:
              #Apply some operations
    return function

calc_diff = function_generator('arg1')
output = Data.groupBy("msn").apply(calc_diff)
```

Comment: This pattern helped me also in a case where I had to deal with schemes not known to me at a certain stage; I could pass them as an argument, too.

Answer (score 11):

You can create the pandas udf inside your function, so that the function arguments are known to it a the time of its creation.  (Or you can import functools and use partial function evaluation to do the same thing.)  Here is the [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html) from the PySpark documentation, modified to pass in some parameters:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))


def my_function(df, by="id", column="v", value=1.0):
    schema = "{} long, {} double".format(by, column)

    @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def subtract_value(pdf):
        # pdf is a pandas.DataFrame
        v = pdf[column]
        g = pdf[by]
        return pdf.assign(v = v - g * value)

    return df.groupby(by).apply(subtract_value)

my_function(df, by="id", column="v", value=2.0).show()
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers seemed useful, but without a formal description of what is happening. So, I took bits and pieces from all and specifically from @sifta and tried to explain it as. Maybe it may help someone in the future.

Let's say I have a PySpark DF as follows

```
# test = pd.DataFrame({
# 'c1': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
# 'c2': ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b1', 'b2']})
# test = spark.createDataFrame(test)

+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  a| a1|
|  a| a2|
|  b| b1|
|  b| b1|
|  b| b2|
+---+---+
```

My aim is to create another column `c3` which can be `group count + some fixed value`. Okay, definitely this is not the best example, but let's try to solve it using groupby. We need to pass the argument (the fixed value) which is kind of not supported directly.

So, following the answers, we can come up with

```
schema = t.StructType([
  t.StructField('c1', t.StringType()),
  t.StructField('c2', t.StringType()),
  t.StructField('c3', t.IntegerType()),
])

def fn_wrapper(df, val):

  @f.pandas_udf(schema, f.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
  def fn(pdf):
    pdf['c3'] = pdf.shape[0] + val
    return pdf

  return df.groupby('c1', 'c2').apply(fn)

fn_wrapper(test, 7).show()
```

but what exactly does it mean?

We have the schema which is used to map the Pandas DF returned by fn (`return pdf`).

So, let's understand how the trick works. We have defined a normal UDF called `fn_wrapper` that takes the Pyspark DF and the argument to be used in the core pandas groupby. We call it in `fn_wrapper(test, 7).show()`. Now, when we are inside the `fn_wrapper`, we just have a function body inside it will just be compiled at the time being and not executed.

Next, the statement `return df.groupby('c1', 'c2').apply(fn)` is executed. See, we have the function `fn` defined as a Pandas UDF and it does not have any arguments. However, we are still inside the `scope of fn_wrapper` when `fn is called as apply` and it has `val` defined. So, we can easily refer to val in `pdf['c3'] = pdf.shape[0] + val` where we have the grouped data present as a Pandas DataFrame.

I guess this helps to understand the wrapping of the functions as a function inside a function and how to Pandas UDF with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do something like this

```
def myfun(data, key, interval):
    #Apply some operations
    return something

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def myfun_udf(data):
    return myfun(data=data, key=mykey, interval=myinterval)


mykey=1
myinterval=2

Data.groupBy("msn").apply(myfun_udf)
```

Comment: I tried the above, it does not work! because the global variables mykey and myinterval that were defined are not used by the udf, rather everytime I change the two arguments I have to re run the grouped map udf definition for them to get updated!