# How can I perform this groupBy + agg in a more efficient manner by using RDD functions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate, user-defined-functions

Let's say I create a new DataFrame like this

```py
import random
import string
data = []
for i in range(100_000):
    rid = string.ascii_uppercase[random.randint(0, len(string.ascii_uppercase) - 1)]
    # gen rand val for col1
    a = random.randint(1, 10)
    # gen rand val for col2
    b = random.randint(1, 10)
    # gen rand val for col3
    c = string.ascii_lowercase[random.randint(0, len(string.ascii_lowercase) - 1)]
    data.append((rid, a, b, c))

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=data,
    schema=["rid", "col1", "col2", "col3"],
)
df.printSchema()
df.orderBy(sf.col("rid")).show(truncate=False)
```

The query I am running right now looks like this

```py
(
    df
    .select("*")
    .groupBy("rid")
    .agg(
        sf.collect_list(sf.col("col1")).alias("cnt1"),
        sf.collect_list(sf.col("col2")).alias("cnt2"),
        sf.collect_set(sf.col("col3")).alias("cnt3")
    )
    .select(
        "rid",
        custom_udf_1('cnt1'),
        custom_udf_2('cnt2'),
        custom_udf_3('cnt3')
    )
    ...
)
```

How can I do this in a more efficient manner? The main objective is to try and do as much of the aggregation within each partition... and only shuffle in the end when we really need to. I do not want to perform a huge shuffle in the beginning... and THEN start aggregating.

I was thinking that it should be possible to convert from `SparkDataFrame` to `RDD` so that I can use functions such as `groupByKey`, `reduceByKey`, or `combineByKey`. However, I am having troubles actually trying to use these functions to achieve my goal.

Here's the only thing I managed to attempt which does not work. Note that this does not include using **UDFs**, only the groupBy+aggregation part.

```py
def createCombiner(row):
    return ([row["col1"]], [row["col2"]], {row["col3"]})

def mergeValue(accumulator, row):
    col1_list, col2_list, col3_set = accumulator
    col1_list.append(row["col1"])
    col2_list.append(row["col2"])
    col3_set.add(row["col3"])
    return (col1_list, col2_list, col3_set)

def mergeCombiners(accumulator1, accumulator2):
    col1_list1, col2_list1, col3_set1 = accumulator1
    col1_list2, col2_list2, col3_set2 = accumulator2
    return (col1_list1 + col1_list2, col2_list1 + col2_list2, col3_set1.union(col3_set2))


combined = df.rdd.combineByKey(createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners)
result = (
    combined
    .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1], list(x[1][2])))
    .toDF(["rid", "collect_list(col1)", "collect_list(col2)", "collect_set(col3)"])
)
result.show()
```

Comment: Using RDDs will likely hurt your performance, no improve it. In general, SQL operations are much faster, especially in pyspark.

Comment: You can use PandasUDF on a grouped data to make custom_udf_1 faster. Example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917006/using-grouped-map-pandas-udfs-with-arguments  As the other person said don't use RDD.

Comment: If you give us an example of custom_udf_1 in pyspark, then maybe we can help.

Comment: @RinatVeliakhmedov I am working with very large data and avoiding huge shuffles could potentially be super helpful. The concept of being able to aggregate as much as possible within partitions before doing a much smaller shuffle to finish the process off seems like it really could improve overall performance. Even if it might hurt my performance I would highly appreciate help on how I can use RDDs to achieve my goal. It's good to learn new ways of doing things, and I can always compare the two with benchmarks to really know what will be better in my specific case.

Comment: @user238607 An example would be to calculate column-sums (take element i from each array and sum, do so for all indices i), do the same but min and max instead of sum. In reality they could be slightly more complicated as more stuff than just that is done to produce other columns too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG` which can be used inside a groupby clause.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from typing import Iterator, Tuple
import pandas as pd

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)




data1 = [
    ["01001", 12, 41, 10],
    ["01004", 66, 1, 77],
    ["01003", 31, 52, 10],
    ["01004", 27, 11, 91],
    ["01001", 43, 5, 10 ],
    ["01003", 21, 11, 2 ],
    ["01003", -61, 15, 10],
    ["01001", 67, -11, -22],
    ["01004", 21, -26, -13],
    ["01001", 13, -5, 10 ],
    ["01003", 21, 111, -2 ],
    ["01003", 13, 18, 10],
    ["01001", 49, -17, -22],

      ]

df1Columns = ["row_id", "col1", "col2", "col3"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)


print("Given dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)

schema = StructType([StructField('col1', IntegerType()),
                    StructField('col2', IntegerType()),
                    StructField('col3', IntegerType())])


@pandas_udf(ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def custom_sum_udf(col1_series: pd.Series, col2_series: pd.Series, col3_series: pd.Series) -> ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())):
    concat_df = pd.concat([col1_series, col2_series, col3_series], axis=1)
    print("what is the concat df")
    print(concat_df)
    sum_column = concat_df.sum(axis=0).tolist()
    max_column = concat_df.max(axis=0).tolist()
    min_column = concat_df.min(axis=0).tolist()
    print("sum_column", sum_column)
    print("max_column", max_column)
    print("min_column", min_column)
    all_result = [sum_column,  max_column, min_column]

    return all_result

df_new = df1.groupby(F.col("row_id")).agg(custom_sum_udf(F.col("col1"), F.col("col2"), F.col("col3")).alias("reduced_columns")).cache()
print("Printing the column sum, max, min")
df_new.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df_new_sep = df_new.withColumn("sum_over_columns", F.col("reduced_columns").getItem(0))
df_new_sep = df_new_sep.withColumn("max_over_columns", F.col("reduced_columns").getItem(1))
df_new_sep = df_new_sep.withColumn("min_over_columns", F.col("reduced_columns").getItem(2)).drop(F.col("reduced_columns"))
print("Printing the column sum, max, min")
df_new_sep.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given dataframe
+------+----+----+----+
|row_id|col1|col2|col3|
+------+----+----+----+
|01001 |12  |41  |10  |
|01004 |66  |1   |77  |
|01003 |31  |52  |10  |
|01004 |27  |11  |91  |
|01001 |43  |5   |10  |
|01003 |21  |11  |2   |
|01003 |-61 |15  |10  |
|01001 |67  |-11 |-22 |
|01004 |21  |-26 |-13 |
|01001 |13  |-5  |10  |
|01003 |21  |111 |-2  |
|01003 |13  |18  |10  |
|01001 |49  |-17 |-22 |
+------+----+----+----+

+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|row_id|reduced_columns                                |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+
|01001 |[[184, 13, -14], [67, 41, 10], [12, -17, -22]] |
|01003 |[[25, 207, 30], [31, 111, 10], [-61, 11, -2]]  |
|01004 |[[114, -14, 155], [66, 11, 91], [21, -26, -13]]|
+------+-----------------------------------------------+

Printing the column sum, max, min
+------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|row_id|sum_over_columns|max_over_columns|min_over_columns|
+------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|01001 |[184, 13, -14]  |[67, 41, 10]    |[12, -17, -22]  |
|01003 |[25, 207, 30]   |[31, 111, 10]   |[-61, 11, -2]   |
|01004 |[114, -14, 155] |[66, 11, 91]    |[21, -26, -13]  |
+------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe useful to take a step back and think about what you are trying to tune and at what scale.  In particular is your use case only 100k records?  Because if thats the case spark is doing a whole bunch of things that are entirely useless to your particular use case.  This includes, cluster replaced things like inter process and inter instance communication.  shuffle exchanges between hosts and memory related tricks like spilling to disk.  In general, at large scale, dataframes are significantly faster than rdds for a couple reasons.

1. dataframes are higher level and more descriptive than RDDs.  This means that spark can do optimizations like filter predicate push down, column pruning, join type optimization.
2. additionally this descriptive nature of dataframes allows spark to custom compile a highly efficient program for each query that you're doing.  this program eliminates the need for raw scala objects and converts everything into simple binary manipulation that CPUs exelerate at.

https://www.databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html

if you're really really smart and know a million different optimizations you might be able to get near the performance of dataframes.

The situation where dataframes start to fall a behind is in the corner cases.  if the dataset is so small it doesn't need to be exchange there's no point paying the full sort cost an exchange would incur.  There's no point in paying the task management overhead.  theres no point in paying the inter process communication overhead.