# pandas vectorize function using two dataframes

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization, apply, matrix-multiplication

I have the following operation:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def some_calc(x,y):
    x = x.set_index('Cat')
    y = y.set_index('Cat')
    y = np.sqrt(y['data_point2'])
    vec = pd.DataFrame(x['data_point1'] * y)
    grid = np.random.rand(len(x),len(x))
    result = vec.dot(vec.T).mul(grid).sum().sum()
    return result

sample_size = 100
cats = ['a','b','c','d']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Cat':[cats[np.random.randint(4)] for _ in range(sample_size)],
                    'data_point1':np.random.rand(sample_size),
                    'data_point2':np.random.rand(sample_size)})

df2 = df1.groupby('Cat').sum().reset_index()
```

I would like to run `some_calc` across each of the `df2` rows using their relative data points from `df1`.

The code below works well:

```
df2['Apply'] = df2.apply(lambda x: some_calc(x=df1[df1['Cat']==x['Cat']][['Cat','data_point1']], 
                                             y=df1[df1['Cat']==x['Cat']][['Cat','data_point2']]),axis=1)
```

(I reset the index in `df2` because I don't know how to apply across indices.
Also, I'm passing both `Cat` as the index field and `data_point` as vectors to `some_calc` because without an index `v.dot(v.T)` will crunch the dot product into one single number. This errors with `.mul()` because I need the full MxM matrix as opposed to a float value. I might be doing something wrong here though...)

I'm currently exploring how I can vectorize the above so that when `sample_size` grows I will not be hampered by a slow down in the calculation.

I saw that in previous threads you can toggle `raw=True` so that the input deal with `np.array` as opposed to `pd.Series`.

```
df2['ApplyRaw'] = df2.apply(lambda x: some_calc(x=df1[df1['Cat']==x['Cat']][['Cat','data_point1']], 
                                                y=df1[df1['Cat']==x['Cat']]['Cat','data_point2']),axis=1, raw=True)
```

However, it throws an error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I tried omitting `Cat` from the argument but still the same issue.

Are there any code improvements or tricks I can employ that allow me to vectorize the above?
Or do I have to amend `some_calc`?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's possible to vectorize your function since it's a bit complex. However, `some_calc` itself and how it is called can be optimized.

What

```
df2['Apply'] = df2.apply(lambda x: some_calc(x=df1[df1['Cat']==x['Cat']][['Cat','data_point1']], 
                                             y=df1[df1['Cat']==x['Cat']][['Cat','data_point2']]),axis=1)
```

does is basically the same as a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). So instead of creating these groups and applying the function on them, use `groupby` + [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). Simplifying the `some_calc` function as well, we get:

```
def some_calc(df):
    x = df['data_point1'].values
    y = np.sqrt(df['data_point2'].values)
    vec = (x * y).reshape(-1, 1)
    grid = np.random.rand(len(x),len(x))
    result = (vec @ vec.T * grid).sum().sum()
    return result

apply = df1.groupby('Cat').apply(some_calc)
apply.name = 'Apply'
df2.merge(apply, left_on='Cat', right_index=True)
```

The final merge is just to add the results to the `df2` dataframe.

Timings:

```
# original
20.5 ms ± 2.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# above code
3.62 ms ± 668 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: that's a very good suggestion. However, I think I over simplified the problem. The array `grid` in `some_calc` is also an input in some edge cases. I will amend the question to reflect the above. Apologies

Comment: @RealRageDontQuit: I think you missed adding the edit to the question? If it's regarding extra arguments to the apply, you can see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483365/use-pandas-groupby-apply-with-arguments

Comment: A detailed blog post about Pandas performance: https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance